# pandas create new dataframe based on return dict from apply function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Here is a lambda function :

```
def gen_data(a, b, c, _date):

    ret = {
        "Date": _date,
        "a" : foo(a),
        "b" : foo(b),
        "c" : foo(c),
    }

    dfObj = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ret)
    return dfObj
```

I'm calling that lambda function for all the rows of an existing dataframe df. The lambda function performs some operations and returns a dataframe object for each row, now I want to create a new data frame `final` with all the new dfs returned from the function

```
final = pd.DataFrame()


final = df.apply(
    lambda row : gen_data(
        row['a'], 
        row['b'],
        row['c'],
        row['d'],
    ),
    axis = 1
)
```

`final` is not populated after this operation, any thoughts, where I am missing?

Comment: What is `df_list`?

Comment: typo, pls ignore, removed

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach this problem. can you provide a sample `df` and `foo`? The data I'm making up is giving me a column of DataFrames in `final`.

Comment: you are getting one column, we need 4 columns. foo can be anything say sqrt

Comment: Okay. Again, sample data is helpful. I don't see why using a Series -> `dfObj = pd.Series(ret)` would not be the correct answer.

Comment: It does seem strange that you are returning a dataframe in the function. Why not just return the columns modified?

Answer (score -1):

What if you try to return a pandas series and not a DataFrame with gen_data?

```
    df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series([foo(row['a']), 
                                    foo(row['b']), 
                                    foo(row['c']), 
                                    row['d']]), 
             index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'Date'], 
             axis=1)
```